# Hamburger Span menu not showing up

Tags: css, sass

```
&__menu{ //mobile menu

> span{
    display: block;
    width: 26px;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: $darkBlue;
}

  <a href="#" class="header__menu">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </a>
```

I understand that it needs height and width as shown in the code, yet on firefox dev ed and chrome its saying height is 0. can anyone help me on this one its probably down to my error considering im new to web dev but this has worked for me before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using `scss` or `sass` etc..? If not give a red color to background if it works no problem.

Also `span` is a `inline-block` element. You shouldn't `display:block`

Comment: I use Scss files and then use a sass compiler, also i was watching someone doing a tutorial on it, and they somehow got that bit of scss to work. ill give both the answers a try illl come back and let you know how it goes. cheers guys.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SCSS then, here how you can do it.

```
.header {

 &__menu {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
width: 40px;
height: 40px;
justify-content: space-around;
align-items: center;

span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 26px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: black;
}

 }

}
```